# VBA select worksheets in array

Tags: vba, excel

I have named those six worksheets in the form of two arrays to do their tasks independently. May I know why this code would not run properly?

The error was in `Sheets(i).Select`, saying that method of selecting worksheet class failed. I did try to change to `.Activate` but the code seems not to run.

```
MyArray = Array("CPWAEB", "CPWAFB", "CRRTPN", "CRRTQN")
MyArray1 = Array("ACM", "GMRTR")

For Each i In MyArray
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("G12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("G7")
Next i

For Each j In MyArray1
    Sheets(j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
Next j
```

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to do? What should the code do?

Comment: `Sheets(MyArray(i))`

Comment: @FunThomas it shows type mismatch.

Comment: @Wernerson Simply in the sheets in MyArray, do goalseek and for another one, calculate sheets in MyArray1

Comment: @Ang  Yiwei: Sorry, misread your code. `i` is usually used as an integer to loop over an array, but in your case it is a string, with the array member, so forget about my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the worksheets in your Workbook like this:

```
For Each i In MyArray
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        .Range("G12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range("G7")
    End With
Next i

For Each j In MyArray1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j)
        .Calculate
    End With
Next j
```

Make sure all cells (G12) have a formula in them, otherwise GoalSeek will fail.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it should look like following a good practice. Avoid using either Select or Activate which is a bad practice.

```
Option Explicit 'Very first line ensures that every variable is declared properly.

Public Sub MySub()
    Dim MyArray() As Variant, MyArray1() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    MyArray = Array("CPWAEB", "CPWAFB", "CRRTPN", "CRRTQN")
    MyArray1 = Array("ACM", "GMRTR")

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        With Worksheets(MyArray(i))
            .Range("G12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range("G7")
        End With
    Next i

    For i = LBound(MyArray1) To UBound(MyArray1)
        Worksheets(MyArray1(i)).Calculate
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you run into errors make sure all the worksheet names in the array really exist as a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyArray, i
    MyArray = Array("CPWAEB", "CPWAFB", "CRRTPN", "CRRTQN")

    For Each i In MyArray
        ' Sheets(i).Select => This won't work when Sheets(i) is not active one
        Sheets(i).Activate ' First activate
        Range("G12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("G7") ' Then use the Range on active sheet
    Next i

    ' When not necessary to activate the sheets
    ' you can use Sheets with array as parameter
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets(MyArray)
        sh.Range("G12").Value = sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub
```